# Interface constant declaration example in Java's SDK

Tags: java, interface, constants

Is there an example of an Interface in Java's built-in library (JDK) that contains a constant field?

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html), constant declaration can be defined in interfaces, but I can't remember seeing such.

```
public interface OperateCar {

   // constant declarations, if any
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
package java.text;

public interface CharacterIterator extends Cloneable
{
    /**
     * Constant that is returned when the iterator has reached either the end
     * or the beginning of the text. The value is '\\uFFFF', the "not a
     * character" value which should not occur in any valid Unicode string.
     */
    public static final char DONE = '\uFFFF';
```

But generally, it is hard to find constants in JDK interfaces, since it does not fit the language convention.

Answer (score 1):

Every field of your `interface` is implicitly `public static final`, thus making it a constant.

So:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String FOO = "foo";
}
```

... is the same as:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public static final String FOO = "foo";
}
```

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I did. Although I interpreted it not so much as "can you find me an interface in Java's source that contains a constant", but rather as, "how does a constant declaration look like in an interface". Semantics I guess.